# ImportError when trying to install pip in Python 3.3.4

Tags: python

While running a command on cmd it shows this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\kids\appdata\local\temp\tmp6y3t4g\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 11, in <module>
      File "c:\users\kids\appdata\local\temp\tmp6y3t4g\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
      File "c:\users\kids\appdata\local\temp\tmp6y3t4g\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 25, in <module>
      File "c:\users\kids\appdata\local\temp\tmp6y3t4g\pip.zip\pip\_internal\locations.py", line 18, in <module>
      File "c:\users\kids\appdata\local\temp\tmp6y3t4g\pip.zip\pip\_internal\utils\appdirs.py", line 16, in <module>
      File "c:\users\kids\appdata\local\temp\tmp6y3t4g\pip.zip\pip\_internal\utils\compat.py", line 66, in <module>
    ImportError: cannot import name cache_from_source
```

PLS: I am using Windows 7 and Python 3.3.4

Comment: I'm not sure how you installed python, but i would do a clean install from start. I suggest Installing [anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/) which doesn't require administrative privileges, includes Python and also gives you access tools like ```pip```.